# How to create topics and the consumer notices it immediately

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have 2 apps that are producer and also consumer to different topics.

After start they need about 4 - 5m if they can consume topics - but the producer already sent a message.

After a restart of the apps it works immediately.

I have a standard config.

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers = localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = myapp1
```

Every app has a different group-id (myapp1, myapp2).

I think is is because my apps create topics at start and this is not immediatelly noticed by the opposite consumer. If I restart my apps the topics are already available.

Any idea I can handle this without waiting some time after 1st start.

I tried multiple settings without success.

```
spring.kafka.admin.properties.request.timeout.ms = 1000
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.request.timeout.ms = 1000
spring.kafka.producer.properties.request.timeout.ms = 1000
spring.kafka.admin.properties[request.timeout.ms] = 1000
spring.kafka.consumer.properties[request.timeout.ms] = 1000
spring.kafka.producer.properties[request.timeout.ms] = 1000
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset = earliest
spring.kafka.advertised.listeners = localhost
```